# why is my code always returning the same result regardless of input?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write a program that takes a parameter n and returns 1+1/2+1/3...+1/n, but whenever it's given any argument greater than 0 it always returns 1.0. can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
public double sumUpTo(int n){
    if(n>1){
        return (1/(n-1))+sumUpTo(n-1);
    }else if(n==1){
        return 1;
    }else if(n==0){
        return 0.0;
    }else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Read about integer division.

Comment: See the question [Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Comment: The problem is, that `1/x` where `x>1` is `0` in integer division. A simple fix would be to write `1.0/(n-1)`.